# Como chamar um script Python em um código C++ no Qt creator?

Tags: c++, python, qt, script

Como faço para chamar um script Python em um código C++ no Qt creator?

Comment: Por favor, gostaria de algum exemplo. Agradeço desde já!!

Comment: Você pesquisou sobre o assunto? Se encontrou algo, edite a pergunta com o que achou.

Comment: Pesquisei, mas não consegui chamar um script python. Ainda aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 2):

Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932353/1606920), o jeito de chamar um script python qualquer pelo Qt é:

```
QProcess p;
p.start("python", "script.py");
```

Lembre-se que é necessário ter o python no Path da máquina.